# CsvHelper writes an empty first line header

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

This is the standard code which has been documented by CsvHelper library to enable header row to be prined when generating CSV files

```
var dbAccounts = _dbcontext.Accounts.ToList();
            using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(path, false, Encoding.GetEncoding(28591)))
            {
                using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(textWriter, _csvConfiguration))
                {
                    csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CsvMappedAccount>();

                    csvWriter.WriteHeader<CsvMappedAccount>(); 

                    foreach (var dbAccount in dbAccounts)
                    {
                        csvWriter.WriteRecord(dbAccount); 
                    } 

                    textWriter.Flush();
                }
            }
```

And this is the registered class

```
 public sealed class CsvMappedAccount: CsvClassMap<Account>
    {
        public CsvMappedAccount()
        {
            Map(m => m.ID).Name("ID");
            Map(m => m.Name).Name("AccountName");
            Map(m => m.AccountNo).Name("AccountNo");
        }
    }
```

However the first line is simply printed empty while second line is printing actual records just fine although this line is explicit in the code above

```
csvWriter.WriteHeader<CsvMappedAccount>();
```

I have tried the official website and the documentation, none seem to have this issue and no different implementation is suggested for enabling header row print.

Library https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper

Comment: You are passing the configuration class type, while it should be the "record" class type, e.g. `WriteHeader<Account>()`

Comment: Ah you are actually right, that was the problem, if you post this as an answer I will happilly accpet this.

Comment: Don't worry, glad it helped, let move on :)